# Set behavior in scala

Tags: scala

Today I noticed that Scala has different behavior for its own Set types than for its wrapped sets (at least SetWrapper). I have an application that leverages existing Java code that performs a simple 'contains' on a Java Set. So, when calling from Scala, I am using scala.collection.JavaConverters to get the implicits necessary to pass in a Java set to this function (SetWrapper). However, the value being checked for existence in the set may be a Java null. It seems that passing a null value into the SetWrapper.contains method causes an NPE. This is the offending snippet from SetWrapper.contains:

```
override def contains(o: Object): Boolean = {
  try { underlying.contains(o.asInstanceOf[A]) }
  catch { case cce: ClassCastException => false }
}
```

It seems that the asInstanceOf invocation is causing the NPE. I am on version 2.11.8 if Scala. Does anyone know if this has been addressed in later versions? I have not found any reference to this issue.

*** More information

The error is occurring on Spark nodes when broadcasting the SetWrapper. If the 'native' Scala Set is sent and the 'asJava' method is called on the node, there are no problems. Apparently SetWrapper does not serialize the underlying Scala set when broadcasting it over the network and it ends up being null on the target nodes.

Comment: I have scala 2.12 and the method signature for SetWrapper contains in my scala is - def contains(elem: A): Boolean = underlying.contains(elem)

Comment: I just checked the source in github (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Wrappers.scala) and it is showing the same method as my original post.

Comment: Using `null` is anyway not recommanded